# Order of model in formula in aggregate function in R

Tags: r, aggregate

If I use aggregate on a dataframe with formula, ie.

```
aggregate(cbind(a,b,c)~d+e+f,df,sum)
```

Does the order of the model columns (d,e,f) matter?

I have this question because I have read something on other website stating that the ordering matters in Reshape.

> The basic arguments of *cast is the molten data and a formula of the form x1 + x2 ~ y1 + y2. The order of the variables matter, the first varies slowest, and the last fastest.

https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/reshape-and-aggregate-data-with-the-r-package-reshape2/

Comment: You can check it by testing on a small dataset

Comment: I have tested it with some small dataset and some sample dataset in r. But you can only be sure unless you know the exact reason or the implementation of aggregate and formula. The ordering may not matter if the dataset is simple enough or data are not fluctating enough. It may matter on a very large, complex dataset.

Comment: Note that the ordering of the variables only matters for the order of the output. You'll get the same numbers regardless of the order of the variables

Answer (score 0):

It affects the order of the rows and of the columns as seen in the example below using the built-in `CO2` data frame.  From the output below we see that the columns specified on the right hand side of the formula are output in the order given in the formula and the rows are in reverse odometer order with the first column varying fastest.

```
levels(CO2$Type)
## [1] "Quebec"      "Mississippi"

levels(CO2$Treatment)
## [1] "nonchilled" "chilled"   

aggregate(cbind(conc, uptake) ~ Treatment + Type, CO2, mean)
##    Treatment        Type conc   uptake
## 1 nonchilled      Quebec  435 35.33333
## 2    chilled      Quebec  435 31.75238
## 3 nonchilled Mississippi  435 25.95238
## 4    chilled Mississippi  435 15.81429

aggregate(cbind(conc, uptake) ~ Type + Treatment, CO2, mean)
##          Type  Treatment conc   uptake
## 1      Quebec nonchilled  435 35.33333
## 2 Mississippi nonchilled  435 25.95238
## 3      Quebec    chilled  435 31.75238
## 4 Mississippi    chilled  435 15.81429
```

Comment: Exactly. The numbers are the same but the ordering might be different.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and I believe this should be the correct behavior. But there was (is) a bug with the ordering of models in some version of R. You may check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15116

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15004

It looks like there was (is) a bug on aggregate.data.frame:

I used the RData provided in the first link to reproduce the issue with R-2.15.3

The output will be different by changing the order of variables

```
> str(data_sample)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ status         : Factor w/ 9 levels "200","302","303",..: 2 2 2
 $ X.videoplayer  : Factor w/ 169 levels "","1154414614001",..: 69 72 72
 $ account_id     : Factor w/ 7 levels "","1661991833001",..: 1 1 1
 $ accountid      : Factor w/ 118 levels "","1012353585001",..: 1 1 1
 $ aifp           : Factor w/ 2 levels "","v0002": 1 1 1
 $ allowfullscreen: Factor w/ 2 levels "","false": 2 2 2
 $ and_tags       : Factor w/ 322 levels "","modelid:103",..: 1 1 1
 $ assetid        : Factor w/ 22 levels "","1880605246001",..: 1 1 1
 $ audioonly      : Factor w/ 2 levels "","false": 1 1 1
 $ auth           : Factor w/ 3 levels "","daeagc2c8codkdja2cucodma8c2boahcecq-bqratw-bwg-acbqrwnkhhhb",..: 1 1 1
 $ bclid          : Factor w/ 15 levels "","1151559591",..: 1 1 1
 $ block          : Factor w/ 2 levels "","true": 1 1 1
 $ bytes_sent     : Factor w/ 10084 levels "1000","10007",..: 9660 9692 9660
 $ leafcount      : num  1 1 1
> aggregate(cbind(leafcount)~status+X.videoplayer+account_id+accountid+aifp+allowfullscreen+and_tags+assetid+audioonly+auth+bclid+bytes_sent+block,data_sample,sum)
  status X.videoplayer account_id accountid aifp allowfullscreen and_tags assetid audioonly auth bclid bytes_sent block leafcount
1    302 1874470124001                                     false                                              758               1
2    302    1882714731                                     false                                              758               1
3    302    1882714731                                     false                                              772               1
> aggregate(cbind(leafcount)~status+X.videoplayer+account_id+accountid+aifp+allowfullscreen+and_tags+assetid+audioonly+auth+bclid+block+bytes_sent,data_sample,sum)
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, len + i, value = c(2, 1)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 3
```